# How withFile is implemented in haskell

Tags: haskell

Following a [haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#files-and-streams), the author provides the following implementation of the **withFile** method:

```
withFile' :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO a) -> IO a  
withFile' path mode f = do  
    handle <- openFile path mode   
    result <- f handle  
    hClose handle  
    return result
```

But why do we need to wrap the `result` in a `return`? Doesn't the supplied function `f` already return an `IO` as can be seen by it's type `Handle -> IO a`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right: `f` already returns an `IO`, so if the function were written like this:

```
withFile' path mode f = do  
    handle <- openFile path mode   
    f handle
```

there would be no need for a return. The problem is `hClose handle` comes in between, so we have to store the result first:

```
result <- f handle
```

and doing `<-` gets rid of the `IO`. So `return` puts it back.

Comment: Oh d'oh! Completely missed the _sucking_ `<-` operator!

Comment: Could it also be `let result = f handle; hClose handle; result` or did I fail monad comprehension again?

Comment: @delnan that would be `do { handle <- openFile mode path; hClose handle; f handle; }`, so `f handle` would probably complain about a closed handle.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Right, brain fart. The resulting IO value ("action") wouldn't be evaluated just from the `let`.

Comment: @drozzy An alternative ending: `f handle >>= \result -> hClose handle >> return result`. Here `>>=` is used to get rid of `IO`, I hope you didn't miss `>>=` too. There are many different suckings, e.g. `>=>` and their reverse counterparts `=<<` and `<=<`.

Comment: Cool, I think I actually understood what `>>=` means just now. Weird, that it would be because of this comment as opposed to Learnyouhaskell book!

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the tricky little things that confused me when I first tried Haskell. You're misunderstanding the meaning of the `<-` construct in do-notation.  `result <- f handle` doesn't mean "assign the value of `f handle` to `result`"; it means "bind `result` to a value 'extracted' from the monadic value of `f handle`" (where the 'extraction' happens in some way that's defined by the particular Monad instance that you're using, in this case the IO monad).

I.e., for some Monad typeclass m, the `<-` statement takes an expression of type `m a` in the right hand side and a variable of type `a` on the left hand side, and binds the variable to a value.  Thus in your particular example, with `result <- f handle`, we have the types `f result :: IO a`, `result :: a` and `return result :: IO a`.

PS do-notation has also a special form of `let` (without the `in` keyword in this case!) that works as a pure counterpart to `<-`.  So you could rewrite your example as:

```
withFile' :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO a) -> IO a  
withFile' path mode f = do  
    handle <- openFile path mode   
    let result = f handle  
    hClose handle  
    result
```

In this case, because the `let` is a straightforward assignment, the type of `result` is `IO a`.

Comment: Cool! I call the `<-` the suck operator, as it sucks the value out of the rhs :-)